# How to make Intent to Browser inside the Adapter of RecyclyrView

Tags: android-intent, kotlin, android-recyclerview

List items contain links to web pages. When you click on an item, the browser in which the link opens should be called. The problem is that when you try to call Intent, an error occurs that is related to context.

Help fix the error, and if possible, write the correct way. Thanks

```
class NewsAdapter(val newsList: NewsList): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolderNews>() {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    return newsList.results.count()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): CustomViewHolderNews {

    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context)
    val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_row, p0, false)

    return CustomViewHolderNews(cellForRow)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolderNews, position: Int) {

    val item = newsList.results.get(position)
    holder.view.title.text = item.title

    val newsImage = holder.view.news_image
    Picasso.get().load(item.imgs.get(0).img).resize(1000 , 600).centerCrop().into(newsImage)

    newsImage.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(item.site_url))
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
}

class CustomViewHolderNews(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

For initialize adapter

```
private lateinit var adapterNews: NewsAdapter

adapterNews = NewsAdapter(arrayList, mContext)
```

For adapter

```
NewsAdapter(private val arrayList: ArrayList<String>, private val mContext: Activity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolderNews>() {


newsImage.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(item.site_url))
    mContext.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: i try this with 'cotext.startActivity()', but it doesn't work too. Error: unresolved reference

Comment: You need to pass context into your adapter

Comment: Where you from call your adapter

Comment: could you explain, approx, where it is to determine and how to transfer it